# query to fetch x starting with letter x having highest x

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I Have 2 models

```
class Author(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField()
    body = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey('Author', related_name='articles', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

what will be the query to fetch all those author whose name start with "a" and have written more than 6 articles.

Answer (score 2):

You can annotate the `QuerySet` with the number of related `Article`s and then filter, like:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Author.objects.annotate(
    narticle=Count('articles')
).filter(
    name__startswith='a',
    narticle__gt=6
)
```

In case the name can start with `A` or `a`, you can replace the [**`__startswith`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#startswith) with the [**`__istartswith`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#istartswith).

In case six articles is sufficient as well, you can replace the [**`__gt`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#gt) with the [**`__gte`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#gte).

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this

```
Author.objects.annotate(count_articles=Count('articles')).filter(
    name__regex=r'^a+',
    count_articles__gt=6
)
```

It annotates and then filters using regex expression and your application logic of being greater than 6.